# cannot be cast to Java

Tags: java

Facing a problem that I can't use my function where I try to update my ArrayList element. Receiving error:

> com.wep.Darbuotojas cannot be cast to com.wep.Programuotojas

I guess that I try somewhere to cast from String to int or from int to String, but just can't see right now where.

Darbuotojas class:

```
package com.wep;

public class Darbuotojas {

protected String vardas;
protected String pavarde;

public String getVardas() {
    return vardas;
}

public void setVardas(String vardas) {
    this.vardas = vardas;
}

public String getPavarde() {
    return pavarde;
}

public void setPavarde(String pavarde) {
    this.pavarde = pavarde;
}

public int getAmzius() {
    return amzius;
}

public void setAmzius(int amzius) {
    this.amzius = amzius;
}

protected int amzius;
Darbuotojas() {}
public Darbuotojas(String vardas, String pavarde, int amzius) {
    this.vardas = vardas;
    this.pavarde = pavarde;
    this.amzius = amzius;
}
```

}

Programuotojas class:

```
package com.wep;

public class Programuotojas extends Darbuotojas {
protected String programavimoKalba;

@Override
public String toString() {
   return "Programuotojas: " + vardas + " " + pavarde + " " + amzius + " " + programavimoKalba;
}
public void setProgramavimoKalba(String programavimoKalba) {
    this.programavimoKalba = programavimoKalba;
}

public Programuotojas(String vardas, String pavarde, int amzius, String programavimoKalba) {
    super(vardas, pavarde, amzius);
    this.programavimoKalba = programavimoKalba;
}
}
```

And here's my function where I try to update everything

```
private ArrayList<Darbuotojas> darbuotojuArray = new ArrayList<Darbuotojas>();
private Darbuotojas darbuotojas = new Darbuotojas();
private void atnaujintiDarbuotoja() {
    if (darbuotojuArray.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Darbuotoju sarasas tuscias. Pridekite nauju darbuotoju");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < darbuotojuArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + i + " " + darbuotojuArray.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite kuri darbuotoja norite atnaujinti");
        Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userSelectsEmployeeID = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
        if (darbuotojuArray.get(userSelectsEmployeeID) instanceof Programuotojas) {
            System.out.println("Iveskite varda");
            String naujasVardas = SI.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Iveskite pavarde");
            String naujaPavarde = SI.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Iveskite amziu");
            int naujasAmzius = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Iveskite nauja programavimo kalba");
            String naujaKalba = SI.nextLine();
            Programuotojas darbProgramuotojas = (Programuotojas) darbuotojas;
            darbProgramuotojas.setVardas(naujasVardas);
            darbProgramuotojas.setPavarde(naujaPavarde);
            darbProgramuotojas.setAmzius(naujasAmzius);
            darbProgramuotojas.setProgramavimoKalba(naujaKalba);
   }...
```

Comment: `Programuotojas darbProgramuotojas = (Programuotojas) darbuotojas;` This line seems to be the problem. `darbuotojas` is an object of Type `Darbuotojas`, which you are trying to cast to `Programuotojas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Darbuotojas cannot be cast to Programuotojas` is pretty clear, and does not deal with `int to String` or `String to int`

Because you have `Programuotojas extends Darbuotojas` you could save a `Programuotojas` instance in a `Darbuotojas` object, but not in the other side, imagine another class `Foo extends Darbuotojas` you can't do

```
Darbuotojas foo = new Foo();
Programuotojas bar = (Programuotojas) foo;
```

Which is what you're trying to do here

```
Programuotojas darbProgramuotojas = (Programuotojas) darbuotojas;
```

---

***Solution :*** 
It just seems that you used the wrong element, (after check the `instance of`) and you  want :

```
if (darbuotojuArray.get(userSelectsEmployeeID) instanceof Programuotojas) {
    //...
    Programuotojas darbProgramuotojas = (Programuotojas) darbuotojuArray.get(userSelectsEmployeeID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because `Programuotojas extends Darbuotojas` it is not the case that Darbuotojas **is** Programuotojas hence the cast is illegal. In other words super class can not be cast to sub class